# How can I make my app a windows 10 default app for photos

Tags: windows, registry, nsis

I have created an application as an exe. On windows 10, if you open the settings app -> Apps -> Default Apps, you can select apps as a default for photos, videos e.t.c. I would like to enable this for my exe. Can this be done via the windows registry?
Also, my app can open unconventional image files like webp and apng. How do I enable this also from the registry.
I am using NSIS for the installer.
Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the documentation for [Registering an Application for Use with Default Programs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/default-programs#registering-an-application-for-use-with-default-programs):

```
!define MyAppUniqueName "MyCompany.MyApp"
!define MyCapabilitiesKey "Software\MyCompany\MyApp\Capabilities"
!define MyProgId "MyCompany.MyApp.File"

Section
WriteRegStr ShCtx "Software\Classes\${MyProgId}\shell\open\command" "" '"$InstDir\myapp.exe" "%1"'

WriteRegStr ShCtx "${MyCapabilitiesKey}" "ApplicationName" "Blah"
WriteRegStr ShCtx "${MyCapabilitiesKey}" "ApplicationDescription" "Blah blah blah"
WriteRegStr ShCtx "${MyCapabilitiesKey}\FileAssociations" ".webp" "${MyProgId}
WriteRegStr ShCtx "${MyCapabilitiesKey}\FileAssociations" ".apng" "${MyProgId}"
WriteRegStr ShCtx "Software\RegisteredApplications" "${MyAppUniqueName}" "${MyCapabilitiesKey}"
SectionEnd

Section Uninstall
DeleteRegKey ShCtx "Software\Classes\${MyProgId}"

DeleteRegValue ShCtx "Software\RegisteredApplications" "${MyAppUniqueName}"
DeleteRegKey ShCtx "${MyCapabilitiesKey}"
SectionEnd
```